# What is the problem with this php generated javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, hosting

On the host the php generates javascript which drops an error of:
missing ; before statement

the generated code was :

```
try{
   obj = document.getElementById('subcat');
    
    }catch(e){}

try{
    obj.innerHTML = "<select name=\"sub_ad_category_id\">   
                          <option value=\"\">-</option>
                          <option value=\"5\">bootle</option>
                          <option value=\"3\">Puzzle</option>
                     </select>";
     }catch(e){}
```

It is generated by action.php with this code:

```
if($var_type=='array') $text = '<select name="+ads_data[sub_ad_category_id]+">';
    else  $text = '<select name="sub_ad_category_id">';
    $text .=   '<option value="">-</option>';
           $res = $ads->get_ads_categories($_SESSION['lang'],$parent_id);
            while($r = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                $text .= '<option value="'.$r['ad_category_id'].'">'.$r['category_name'].'</option>';
            }
    $text .= '</select>';

    echo "try{obj = document.getElementById('".$id."');}catch(e){}";
    echo "try{obj.innerHTML = ".$text.";}catch(e){}";
```

Comment: I think you have to use single quote in the string or escape your double quotes

Comment: You're missing + in concatenation

Comment: "... in localhost it works fine" I bet the code doesn't work in any host. If it looks like it would, you're probably running a different code from the cache.

Comment: also Javascript execution doesn't depend on hosting cause this part seems to be client-side as far as you say that you test it in Firefox

Comment: It definitely doesn't work in any environment. Please see my comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this line ...

```
obj.innerHTML = "<select name="sub_ad_category_id"><option value="">-</option></select>";
```

... modifications (missing some `+` signs and changed double quotes at value to single `''`)

```
obj.innerHTML = "<select name=" + sub_ad_category_id + "><option value=''>-</option></select>";
```

- The `+` is simple concatenation.
- The `''` single quotes is one way of including quotes in final HTML cleanly; otherwise, you could have used `\"\"` slash escaped quotes.

**UPDATE**:

Given what I see of your changes above, it looks like how you are building the string.  Don't use the enter key when building strings.  Try like this ...

```
var html = "<select name=\"sub_ad_category_id\">";
html += "<option value=\"\">-</option>";
html += "<option value=\"5\">bootle</option>";
html += "<option value=\"3\">Puzzle</option>";
html += "</select>";
ob.innerHTML = html;
```

... OR ...

```
ob.innerHTML = "<select name=\"sub_ad_category_id\"><option value=\"\">-</option><option value=\"5\">bootle</option><option value=\"3\">Puzzle</option></select>";
```

See this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/o0bnju0f/)**

Comment: Made some updates and a fiddle to test ... see update.

Comment: Given that, make sure it's one solitary string ... I will update answer.

Comment: It looks like the repeated echoes are causing the issue.  Build one string in PHP and echo that long one out.  Otherwise, you'll have these types of issues.

Comment: This question caused me to be banned 6 years ago, and I am still banned. I can't delete, comment, ask, or anything on this page. I would appreciate if someone could help to remove it. :D